# How do I fix 'cannot render console' when trying to access a rails server from VMWare Fusion Windows 10?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, windows, virtual-machine, vmware-fusion

I am trying to access a Rails app running on my mac through VMWare Fusion Windows 10. When i hit the server at the host ip:3000, I get the error:

`Started GET "/" for 192.246.134.68 at 2018-02-20 09:36:02 -0600
Cannot render console from 192.246.134.68! Allowed networks: 127.0.0.1, ::1, 127.0.0.0/127.255.255.255`

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved this by binding my server to the host ip.
`rails s -b 192.246.134.68`
This however has unveiled my next issue which is getting the above error when I hit the login server.

I can't bind both servers to the same IP address it seems?

Comment: I would like to know as well!